# Migrate if statement from mysql to firebird

Tags: firebird2.5

```
SELECT if((a.status is null)or(a.status='')or(a.status='-'),'Not Submitted Yet',a.status) as OBJ1, 'Cummulative Progress' as obj2, a.project_id, gp.team_name,
        COUNT(DISTINCT(a.task_id)) as NILAI
    FROM task a INNER JOIN 
        site b ON a.site_id=b.site_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
        task_privilige pv ON a.task_id = pv.task_id LEFT OUTER join
        team gp on pv.team_id = gp.team_id LEFT OUTER join 
            task_tenant f ON a.task_id = f.task_id
        WHERE 1 ".$xqr." 
        GROUP BY OBJ1, a.ID, a.PROJECT_ID, a.TASK_ID, a.PHASE, a.SITE_ID, a.ATTACHMENT_FILE, a.PLAN_DATE, a.BAPP, a.STATUS, a.REMARK, a.TASK_TYPE, a.LAST_UPDATE, a.LAST_UPDATER_ID, a.TASK_ID_REFERENCE, a.SOURCE_SITE_ID, a.DESTINATION, a.VENDOR, a.ADMIN_ID, a.ENGINEER_ID, a.MATERIAL_ID, a.REMARK_CHECKER, a.TAG_CHECK, a.TAG_MANUAL,
        b.ID, b.SITE_NAME, b.PERIODE, b.SITE_ID, b.TYPE_SITE, b.BSC, b.ADDRESS, b.AREA, b.CITY, b.LAT, b.LANG, b.RADIUS, b.KETERANGAN, b.LAST_UPDATE, b.LAST_UPDATER_ID,
        pv.ID, pv.TASK_ID, pv.TEAM_ID, pv.LAST_UPDATE, pv.LAST_UPDATER_ID,
        gp.ID, gp.TEAM_ID, gp.TEAM_NAME, gp.TEAM_LEADER_ID, gp.LAST_UPDATE, gp.LAST_UPDATER_ID,
        f.ID, f.TASK_ID, f.TENANT_NAME, f.TENANT_TYPE
```

Comment: Use a `case` expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`CASE`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-case.html):

```
CASE WHEN a.status IS NULL OR a.status = '' OR a.status = '-'
    THEN 'Not Submitted Yet'
    ELSE a.status
END AS OBJ1
```

Or you can use [`IIF`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-iif.html):

```
IIF(a.status IS NULL OR a.status = '' OR a.status = '-', 
    'Not Submitted Yet', a.status) AS OBJ1
```